# How do I removed selected ng-options from other uses of same ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to reuse an ng-options instance but remove the selected items from previous uses.

I have a plunker started http://plnkr.co/edit/Fx7igqMjPsBQz1vtUlsM?p=preview

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="SelectController">
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="select1">Select 1:</label>
    <select ng-model="newForm.select1" 
            ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in options" 
            class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row"><br></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="select2">Select 2:</label>
    <select ng-model="newForm.select2" 
            ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in options" 
            class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('select', []);

app.controller('SelectController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
   {name: 'Apple', id: '1'},
   {name: 'Orange', id: '2'},
   {name: 'Banana', id: '3'},
   {name: 'Pear', id: '4'},
 ];

});
```

So, for example if select 1 = Apples, I want to remove Apples from the ng-options in select 2.

What's the best way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Second `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="... in options | filter: newForm.select1 && {name: '!' + newForm.select1}"
```

where `newForm.select1` represents the model value of the first selection.

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt7g8xoa/)**

Comment: Wicked!  Thanks Mike.  Thought it should be that simple.

Comment: This can also be chained.  Updated plunker -http://plnkr.co/edit/Fx7igqMjPsBQz1vtUlsM?p=preview